# AntiForgeryToken suggested by SNYK tool

Tags: antiforgerytoken, snyk

I'm solving some issues shown at SNYK tool (https://snyk.io/). I've got this issue:

> Anti-forgery token validation disabled. This ASP.NET MVC action should
> use an anti-forgery validation attribute. Not using this attribute
> disables Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection and allows CSRF
> attacks.

At Controller, this is an `ActionResult` that returns a view where user must choose from some options to continue.

```
<a class="btn" href="/Account/ChooseCompany?Company_id=xxxxxxx"></a>
<a class="btn" href="/Account/ChooseCompany?Company_id=yyyyyyy"></a>
```

Since the user doesn't really post anything, just enters a new URL address (therefore a GET request), I was wondering why does SNYK suggested "anti-forgery token".

Comment: do these endpoints mutate anything?

Comment: Tools like that don't understand the broader context. While its suggestions are usually correct in general cases, it's still up to the developer to examine them to see if they really are appropriate.

Comment: @Ouroborus Yes, I do agree. So your suggestion is that this may be one of these cases where no action is needed, correct?

Comment: @DanielA.White This is a screen where user sets which company environment it actually wants to work. It changes at "session" within server, with the validations being applied accordingly.

Comment: ideally GET requests shouldn't mutate anything, including the session

Comment: @DanielA.White This was one of the first views, built at Razor with ViewBag. I will have a look and probably change this to a POST flow. Thanks

Comment: Being a false positive is always a possibility, but I don't think there's enough context here to clearly say one way or another. Ideally your company would have an information security team that you work with when resolving possible false positives in reports from such tools.

Comment: @Ouroborus and others, thank for your support. I've refactored that page to be a POST request via AJAX, where I've included the "AntiForgeryToken".

Comment: @Ouroborus you did the right thing ....